# Batch-convert pictures in command line

Tags: command-line, convert, batch

I would like to convert a large number of pictures in Konsole. I need pictures resized in order to make a video.

I can do it for one picture; I am satisfied with this command:

```
convert video000001.png -filter Lanczos -resize 50% toto000001.jpeg
```

So my question is how can treat the case with a lot of pictures?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple script. Just create a folder with all the images you want to convert and launch the following script in the same folder :

*img_convert.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash 

FILES=*.png
mkdir -p ./converted
for i in $FILES 
do 
        echo "Processing image $i..." 
        /usr/bin/convert "$i" -filter Lanczos -resize 50% ./converted/converted_"$i".jpeg
done
```

---

Edit:

[@pzkpfw](https://askubuntu.com/users/40689/pzkpfw) pointed out you can simply run this command in your shell for the same result :

```
for i in *.png; do convert "$i" -filter Lanczos -resize 50% converted_"$i".jpeg; done;
```

Comment: Why you don't use `"$i"` instead of `$i`?

Comment: You can also just run `for i in *.png; do convert $i -filter Lanczos -resize 50% converted_$i.jpeg;` straight in the bash prompt without creating a script (in the correct directory). You can also make this an alias in your `.bashrc` if you wish, that way you could run something like `myconversion` in any folder to convert all PNGs to JPEGs.

Comment: @pzkpfw That is a better solution indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution, to my knowledge, is mogrify.

[ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php)

If it's not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

then, in the directory where your .png files are located:

```
mogrify -resize 50% *.png
```

Good luck!